# Xcode project path in prepare_command

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

We'd like to add a runscript phase to the project's target from the cocoapods `prepare_command` script. Is there any environmental variable(like `PROJECT_DIR`) to get the current project path from the `prepare_command` script?

Here are the examples of podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.platform     = :ios
  spec.name         = '...'
...
  spec.prepare_command = <<-CMD
ruby add_phase.rb
CMD
```

and ruby script used to add a build phase:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'xcodeproj'

project_dir = ??
project_files = Dir.glob(File.join(project_dir, "*.xcodeproj"))
...
```